# MS Access update two values from master form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

## Background Information

I have **two** tables interacting in my database issue; `tblCountry_Language` and `tblTerritory_Country`.

`tblCountry_Language` is a Master to Child Relationship, where a Country can have multiple languages spoken within it.

`tblCountry_Language` has the columns `CountryID`,`LanguageID`, and `TerritoryID`.

`tblTerritory_Country` is also a Master to Child Relationship, where a Territory can have multiple Countries within it.

`tblTerritory_Country` has only the columns `TerritoryID` and `CountryID`.

With this information in mind, let's look at the **form** I have constructed:

[image]

The outer form, holding the top two combination boxes of **Country** and **Territory** is a carousel of the records in `tblTerritoryCountry`.

The subform within is from `tblCountry_Language`, and is connected to the master form currently by `CountryID`.
I.E., each of those languages I have filled in the subform get **recorded** with the Country that the container form has into my desired table `tblCountry_Language`.

## My Question

As I've stated, the linked relationship of `CountryID` successfully records the country in my `tblCountry_Language`.

**How do I also make it so that the Territory can be recorded in my `tblCountry_Language` too?** I.E., I can get both the Country *and* the Territory get recorded in the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to record TerritoryID in tblCountry_Language, in fact it would be wrong to do so as it violate database normalization principles. You can use a query to display language-territory info. SQL is as follows

```
Select Distinct LanguageID,TerritoryID  from
tblCountry_Language INNER JOIN tblTerritory_Country
ON tblTerritory_Country.CountryID=tblCountry_Language.CountryID
```

Also, I suggest renaming tblTerritory_Country to simply tblCountry

I am assuming that you also have tblLanguage and tblTerritory as lookup tables for the other two tables that you mentioned in your question. If not I stronly suggest that you create them and change the LanguageID and TerritoryID in tblCountry_Language and tblTerritory_Country respectively to lookup fields.

Comment: I have a tblCountry, it is a reference of all of the countries.
And yes, tblLanguage and tblTerritory are lookup tables.

The reason I need Territory in tblCountry_Language is because I need it as a reference frame for other forms I am running

Comment: Anyway, when I implement your query, I just get a list of all of the territories that have countries in my table, but I do not get just the one that I want

Comment: You definitely do not need Territory in tblCountry_Language because you have already stored Territory  in tblTerritory_Country. Trying to store the same information twice is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Also if the relationship between Country and Territory is one-to-many then you do not need tblTerritory_Country, just a Territory field in tblCountry that look up to tblTerritory.TerritoryID is enough.

It always help to not over complicate a database and getting the table structure right from the start is critical.

Comment: _"Anyway, when I implement your query, I just get a list of all of the territories that have countries in my table, but I do not get just the one that I want"_ 
`tblTerritory_Country.CountryID=tblCountry_Language.CountryID` should give you country in tblTerritory_Country that have language.